# how do I filter a table's data from a dropdown menu-items with react and antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have been trying to at least filter a table based on some string of labels or dropdown menu items (one of them is super admin):
I have tried using useEffect
It filters now if i click on the super admin label. but the userRoleclicked array doesn't update when other labels are selected or deselected. instead it overwrites the array. Also in the UI, you can't click multiple items from the dropdown menu items expect one. I'm stuck and i don't know what to do

the code:

```
const [searchClinicianRoles, setSearchClinicianRoles] = useState<string[]>([]);

useEffect(() => {
        if (searchClinicianRoles.includes("Super admin")) {
            
            const filteredAclsByDropdown = allAcls.filter((a) => a.acl?.super_admin);
            setFilteredAcls(filteredAclsByDropdown);
        }
    }, [searchClinicianRoles, allAcls]);


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//for the filter button
  
  onSelectedItemsChange={(selectedItems) => {
                    
                    const userRolesClicked = selectedItems.map(
                        (selectedItem) => selectedItem.label
                    );

                    
                    setSearchClinicianRoles(userRolesClicked);
                    
                }}
```

this is what i am trying to achieve:

Comment: Hello. "it overwrites the array". The setter function from `useState` will indeed overwrite the array. You will need to manually merge/create the array if that's not the behavior you want, but, shouldn't `selectedItems` have the full set of data such that overriding the array is the correct behavior?

Comment: If possible, Can you share some screenshots/pics of the screen so that we can understand exactly what you are doing? Thank you